# Trouble configuring Spring-boot 2 Actuator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I want to configure the spring-boot Actuator end points for our application.  Below is my pom.xml file with spring-boot actuator dependency added.

When I start the application I don't see any of the /application/ URL endpoints registered as the documentation suggests. The documentation suggests that after adding the actuator dependency to the pom.xml that I should see extra mappings in the startup log, which I don't.   What could be there problem here?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>SpreadSheetUploadWeb</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpreadSheetUploadWeb</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>5.0.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.boot.version>2.0.4.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Actuator for application Health/State monitoring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Here is a startup log:

```
2018-08-08 14:16:40 INFO  o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Schema "DB2INST " is up to date. No migration necessary.
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/bluecost/costspreadsheet/{uploader}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.domain.CostSpreadsheet>> com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.rest.controller.BlueCostRestController.getCostSpreadsheetByUploader(java.lang.String)
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/bluecost/costspreadsheet/{uploader}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.domain.CostSpreadsheet>> com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.rest.controller.BlueCostRestController.getCostSpreadsheetByUploader(java.lang.String)
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/bluecost/sscdata/],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.domain.BluecostSSCData>> com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.rest.controller.BlueCostRestController.getAllBluecostSSCData()
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/bluecost/sscdata/],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.domain.BluecostSSCData>> com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.rest.controller.BlueCostRestController.getAllBluecostSSCData()
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/bluecost/sscdata/],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.rest.controller.BlueCostRestController.createBluecostSSCData(com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.domain.BluecostSSCData)
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/bluecost/sscdata/],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.rest.controller.BlueCostRestController.createBluecostSSCData(com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.domain.BluecostSSCData)
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/bluecost/spreadsheet/upload],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.rest.controller.BlueCostRestController.uploadSpreadsheet(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile)
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/bluecost/spreadsheet/upload],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.rest.controller.BlueCostRestController.uploadSpreadsheet(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile)
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/bluecost/spreadsheet/{uploader}/{filename}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.rest.controller.BlueCostRestController.deleteUploadedSpreadsheet(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/bluecost/spreadsheet/{uploader}/{filename}],methods=[DELETE]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.rest.controller.BlueCostRestController.deleteUploadedSpreadsheet(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/bluecost/sscdata/{uploader}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.rest.controller.BlueCostRestController.findSSCDataByUploader(java.lang.String)
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/bluecost/sscdata/{uploader}],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.spreadsheet.rest.controller.BlueCostRestController.findSSCDataByUploader(java.lang.String)
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/swagger-resources/configuration/ui]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.swagger.web.UiConfiguration> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.uiConfiguration()
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/swagger-resources/configuration/ui]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.swagger.web.UiConfiguration> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.uiConfiguration()
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/swagger-resources]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SwaggerResource>> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.swaggerResources()
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/swagger-resources]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.List<springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SwaggerResource>> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.swaggerResources()
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/swagger-resources/configuration/security]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SecurityConfiguration> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.securityConfiguration()
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/swagger-resources/configuration/security]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SecurityConfiguration> springfox.documentation.swagger.web.ApiResourceController.securityConfiguration()
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-08-08 14:16:41 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-08-08 14:16:42 INFO  s.d.s.w.PropertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json> springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2018-08-08 14:16:42 INFO  s.d.s.w.PropertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json> springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2018-08-08 14:16:42 INFO  o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-08-08 14:16:42 INFO  o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-08-08 14:16:42 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@3967e60c: startup date [Wed Aug 08 14:16:34 MDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-08-08 14:16:42 INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@3967e60c: startup date [Wed Aug 08 14:16:34 MDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-08-08 14:16:42 INFO  o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-08-08 14:16:42 INFO  o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-08-08 14:16:42 INFO  o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-08-08 14:16:42 INFO  o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-08-08 14:16:43 INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-08-08 14:16:43 INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2018-08-08 14:16:43 INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2018-08-08 14:16:43 INFO  o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2018-08-08 14:16:43 INFO  s.d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper - Context refreshed
2018-08-08 14:16:43 INFO  s.d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper - Context refreshed
2018-08-08 14:16:43 INFO  s.d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper - Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
2018-08-08 14:16:43 INFO  s.d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper - Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
2018-08-08 14:16:43 INFO  s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner - Scanning for api listing references
2018-08-08 14:16:43 INFO  s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner - Scanning for api listing references
2018-08-08 14:16:43 INFO  o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2018-08-08 14:16:43 INFO  o.a.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool - Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2018-08-08 14:16:44 INFO  o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-08-08 14:16:44 INFO  c.i.c.c.c.s.BlueCostSpreadsheetUploadWebApplication - Started BlueCostSpreadsheetUploadWebApplication in 10.194 seconds (JVM running for 11.014)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working as expected, but the URLs that I've been trying to reach these through were not correct.  I found the real URLs in the spring documentation, and for me they are:

http://localhost:8080/actuator
and
http://localhost:8080/browser.html